# keeping certain columns in R

Tags: r, subset, lapply, sapply

I have a list of dataframes, and I want to loop through them and keep the rows that match with certain values of certain columns names, I want to pass vector of those columns names and their corresponding values.

Example:

```
DF1 =
x   y
10  s
5   h

DF2 =

x  z   y
11  h   h
5   s  s
5   h  s
```

So I want to loop through those dataframes, and keep any rows with (x,y) column names that has values of (5,s).That's just an example, I want to generlize my code.

I'm thinking of this but it sure is not working like this:

```
Data-Mining = sapply(DFlist,)
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I recreate the two `data.frame` objects you provide in your example, and then use `lapply`, and two functions from the `dplyr` package to select and filter based on your desired output. `Select` subsets the columns of interest, and `filter` selects the rows that meet some logical criterion/criteria.

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 = data.frame(x=c(10,5), y=c('s','h'))

DF2 = data.frame(x=c(11,5,5), z=c('h', 's', 'h'), y = c('h','s','s'))


DFlist <- list(DF1, DF2)



colsKeep <- c('x', 'y')
xRange <- 1:5
yVal <- 's'

lapply(DFlist, function(x){x %>% 
                             select(one_of(colsKeep)) %>% 
                             filter(x %in% xRange & y == yVal)})
```

edit: I now specify the columns to keep, and the value(s) that I'll accept in the subset.

Comment: This is an example, can you please generalize the line of "lapply"?

Comment: And can you not use any package?

Comment: Why would you not want to use any package? If it weren't for the number of great packages, I'd drop `R` like it was hot and learn `Julia` as fast as possible.

Comment: @TadDallas - some people, myself included, try to avoid packages that duplicate base functionality. It increases compatibility with everyone else and reduces reliance on the whims of any particular package developer.

Comment: Fair point. In that case, maybe the `subset` function would better suit your needs? It is worth noting that regardless of developer whims, one could use `packrat` to keep package versions consistent, and things like Docker to build workflows that can rely on cool packages and still be reproducible through time and compatible across machines.

Comment: Can you rewrite it and cover any case for colsKeep and the values? considering different length of those vectors

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this, relying on `merge` to keep the rows. Might be easier than writing a selection statement if you have many variables to match. I've added an extra dataset that has neither an `x` or `y` variable present to show how this accounts for that issue.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(x=c(10,5), y=c('s','h'))
DF2 <- data.frame(x=c(11,5,5), z=c('h', 's', 'h'), y = c('h','s','s'))
DF3 <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4)

vals <- list(5, "s")
nams <- c("x","y")
lapply(list(DF1,DF2,DF3), function(DAT) {
  DAT[setdiff(nams, names(DAT))] <- NA
  merge(DAT, setNames(vals,nams), by=nams)
})

#[[1]]
#[1] x y
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#
#[[2]]
#  x y z
#1 5 s s
#2 5 s h
# 
#[[3]]
#[1] x y a b
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: That might be good but it's not generalized, can you generalize it please?

Comment: I don't understand, what is not generalized about it. It can take any combination of input files and values to match - do you want something like `lapply(list(DF1,DF2), function(DAT) DAT[with(DAT, x==5 & y=="s"),] )` instead?

Comment: Column names is a vector that will be passed through a function, and it will change each time also its length will change, and the corresponding values is the same case. If we call the vector of Col names "colunames" and the vector of the corresponding values by "Values", can you show me how I can re-use your code line?

Comment: it returns this error " Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: @lel - well, it works using your example datasets. I can only guess there is something wrong with your input data - possibly a missing `x` or `y` column to merge against.

Comment: Can we try for loop for general ?

Comment: `lapply` is a for-loop under the hood basically, so the same merge code will likely fail whether in an `lapply` or `for loop` if it isn't working here.

Comment: There should be something that will work on any example

Comment: @lel - it works on your example data is all I know. I can make example data that will fail every time, if for instance there is no `x` variable in a data.frame.

Comment: what I meant is, "vals" and "names" can be passed many times with different values and variables and with different length of vectors. The code should not really depend on the dataset.

Comment: I gave an example with fake dataset, but the code I need should work on any dataset and any different vectors.

Comment: @lel - So there may be `DF3` which may have neither an `x` nor a `y` column? That changes things a lot if so.

Comment: @lel - I don't know then. As far as I can tell, this code will work on any input of `nams` and `vals` regardless of the input `DF(1-n)` datasets it is fed and what  variables are present in them.